# Changing Cauchy integral along triangle to an integral along a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't want to tease the whole question. So basically I have a line integral which has a pole in a closed triangular path. I was just wondering if I can draw a circle enclosing this triangular path and evaluate that line integral instead. Would they be equal?

Also if the orientation of the triangular path is clockwise, do I have to revert it by putting $-$ sign?

Comment: When you say "has a pole in a closed triangular path" do you mean that the pole lies on the path itself, or that it is in the interior region enclosed by the triangle?

Comment: it is in the interior region enclosed by the triangle..The vertices of the triangle are 2, 2i and -2 and the pole is at z=i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the circle and the triangle enclose exactly the same singularities of the integrand, the two integrals will be equal.

Changing the direction of the path changes the sign of the integral.

Comment: its been a while since I did complex, but why is this?